# Variable Font Sliders

Tags: javascript, css

For a school project I'm looking at the advantages of the use of variable font. So I'm trying to create a couple of slider to manipulate the font.

In this I'm using the Gingham variable font.

I've managed to get the font-weight slider to work but I can't for the width slider and I can't seem to work it out? I was wondering if anyone knew what I was doing wrong?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Variable Fonts</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Adjust the sliders to modify the Variable Font: Gingham</h1>

  <p id="testarea" contenteditable="true">Type Text Here</p>

  <label for="slider_weight">Weight</label>
  <input type="range" id="slider_weight" name="slider" value="300" min="300" max="700" step="10">
  <span id="value_weight"></span>
  <br>

  <label for="slider_width">Width</label>
  <input type="range" id="slider_width" name="slider" value="100" min="10" max="100" step="1">
  <span id="value_width2"></span>

<script src="js/slider.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('slider_weight').addEventListener("input", function () {
  var axisValue = document.getElementById('slider_weight').value;

  document.getElementById('testarea').style.fontWeight = axisValue;

  document.getElementById('value_weight').innerText = axisValue;
});

document.getElementById('slider_width').addEventListener("input", function () {
  var axisValue2 = document.getElementById('slider_width').value;

  document.getElementById('testarea').style.fontStretch = axisValue2;

  document.getElementById('value_width2').innerText = axisValue2;
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roema8t1/)

Comment: You are not setting a unit.... aka `50%`

Comment: I think it's your `document.getElementById('testarea').style.fontStretch`. Font-Stretch takes a string as it's value, not a number. If you're trying to change the font-size, you'll need to use `fontSize` there instead. Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-stretch/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ranges to your `@font-face` rule for each variable design axis like so:

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Flex';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 1000;
  font-stretch: 0% 200%;
  src: url(fontfile.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Otherwise, the browser can't render interpolated `width` or `weight` values correctly.

```js
slider_weight.addEventListener("input", function () {
  var axisValue = slider_weight.value;
  testarea.style.fontWeight = axisValue;
  value_weight.innerText = axisValue;
});

slider_width.addEventListener("input", function () {
  var axisValue2 = slider_width.value;
  testarea.style.fontStretch = axisValue2+'%';
  value_width.innerText = axisValue2;
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Flex';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 1000;
  font-stretch: 0% 200%;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoflex/v9/NaNeepOXO_NexZs0b5QrzlOHb8wCikXpYqmZsWI-__OGfttPZktqc2VdZ80KvCLZaPcSBZtOx2MifRuWR28sPJtUMbsFEK6cRrleUx9Xgbm3WLHa_F4Ep4Fm0PN19Ik5Dntczx0wZGzhPlL1YNMYKbv9_1IQXOw7AiUJVXpRJ6cXW4O8TNGoXjC79QRyaLshNDUf9-EmFw.woff2) format('woff2');
}


html {
  font-family: 'Roboto Flex';
}

#testarea {
  font-size: 2em;
  transition:0.5s;
  font-weight:100;
  font-stretch: 0%;
}
```

```html
  <p id="testarea" contenteditable="true">Type something ...</p>

  <label for="slider_weight">Weight</label>
  <input type="range" id="slider_weight" name="slider" value="100" min="100" max="1000" step="10">
  <span id="value_weight">100</span>
  <br>

  <label for="slider_width">Width</label>
  <input type="range" id="slider_width" name="slider" value="0" min="0" max="200" step="1">
  <span id="value_width">0</span>
```